# How to save something when crtl+S keys are pressed (UWP app)

Tags: uwp

I want to save something whenever a user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key from keyboard.
 I'm currently Making use of keydown Event Handler but I  only get access to one key pressed at a time not the combination.

Here is my code.

```
private void txtWriteSomething_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (**VirtualKeyModifiers.Control** && e.Key==VirtualKey.Control)
        {
          //how to use VirtualKeyModifiers in this statement?
        }
    }
```

Now to get the combination (according to msdn) we use virtulakeymodifiers enumeration. Here I'm not quite able to get, how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.S)
    {
        MessageDialog _dialog = new MessageDialog("Ctrl+S");
        _dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
};
```

If you see, I subscribed to `Ctrl+S` on `CoreWindow`. If you want to Subscribe this to just a single page, then Subscribe to `KeyDown` on that page.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to keydown event? Like which method in your code behind?